# Is it possible to find the Kafka client version used by the Kafka consumers from the metadata on Kafka brokers?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We want to migrate our Kafka cluster from Kafka 0.9.* to 0.10.* and wanted to have a sanity check to assure that all our JVM Kafka consumers have been upgraded to use Kafka 0.10.* clients.